# What does the error foreach not applicable to type mean for DocumentSnapshot type?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ofkvm97i0s) tutorial to fill a List from an array in firestore. However I get the error that foreach is not applicable to type "DataSnapshot"

I followed the tutorial exactly and am unsure what could cause this error.

Here is what I have:

```java
private void readData(final MyCallback callback){
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                        String group = document.getString("following");
                        followingList.add(group);
                    }
                    callback.onCallback(followingList);
                } else {
                }
            }
        });
    }

 private interface MyCallback {
     void onCallback(List<String> list);
 }
```

I should be able to fill the List from this method but it is not compiling with the error:

```
error: for-each not applicable to expression type
required: array or java.lang.Iterable
found:    DocumentSnapshot
```

Comment: Is `Task` some sort of `Collection`?

Comment: I think that it returns a collection from firestore: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/tasks/Task

Comment: Sorry I can see where the collection is.

Comment: Do you mean like the firestore collection? I'm not sure that is where the issue is, in the linked video this is almost exactly what is done.

Comment: a `foreach` is going to iterate over a `Collection`, so unless `task.getResult()` returns a some sort of `iterable` it is not going to work

Comment: But it should since the task is retrieving an array from firestore.

Comment: see this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`task.getResult()` is going to return an object of type DocumentSnapshot, which doesn't have a foreach method on it that conforms to the Iterable interface.  If you are only going to fetch a single document, there's not going to be multiple documents to iterate over.  Just remove the for loop and access the fields of the document directly:

```
DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
String group = document.getString("following");
followingList.add(group);
```

You will only have documents to iterate over if you are performing a query that could return multiple documents, which you are not doing here.  `get()` just returns one document at most.

Comment: This works. Also I believe you meant```DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();```

Answer (score 4):

As per https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data, you could use a QuerySnapshot

```
db.collection("cities")
    .whereEqualTo("capital", true)
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {   // LOOP
                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your task is not completed. In Android Developer Doc, it describes:

```
Returns  TResult    
Throws IllegalStateException    if the Task is not yet complete
```

So as you saw, the exception cannot use for-each.